# replace last n parts after spliting on delimiter using sed or regex

Tags: regex, sed

I need to replace last 2 parts of the string separated by delimiter with empty space to clean up the name.
Example:

```
something-useful-a12356-78929
```

=>

```
something-useful
```

```
something-more-useful-v35f62-2728902
```

=>

```
something-more-useful
```

I tried the following:

```
echo "something-useful-12345-67890" | sed -re 's/(-([0-9])+)//g'
```

This works if my last 2 elements of delimiter are numbers only, but wouldn't work for the example above. I need to remove the last 2 parts after splitting it on "-"
I can only use sed or regex to solve this.

Comment: Would it always be the last two elements you need to replace? If so, then `(?:-[^-]+){2}$` maybe?

Comment: ```echo 'something-more-useful-v35f62-2728902' | sed -E 's/(.*)(-[^-]+){2}$/\1/'```

Answer (score 2):

Does `sed 's/\(-[^-]*\)\{2\}$//' file` does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^-]` to match anything other than `-`. Use `$` to match the end of the string. Match hyphen followed by non-hyphens twice at the end.

```
sed -r 's/(-[^-]+){2}$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -re 's/-[^-]*//2g' file
```

Removes globally from the second occurrence of `-` followed by non `-` characters.